# How can I use Moles to return different values for multiple calls to a method in C#?

Tags: c#, moles

I've been trying to find a solution for this, but either I've been looking with the wrong search terms or there simply isn't an answer for my question yet.

Problem:
I've got a method that I'd like to write a unit test for. Within this method there is an external dependency that I can't really resolve, so I'll have to use Moles to create my unit test.

This external dependency consists of a method on an instance that is called multiple (two) times, and the second time I'd like to return a different value with Moles.

```
...
bool myVar = SomeInstance.SomeMethod(); // Here I'd like to return true
if( myVar )
...
...
bool myOtherVar = SomeInstance.SomeMethod(); // Here I'd like to return false
...
```

Now usually I set it up like

```
MSomeInstance.SomeMethod.AllInstances.SomeMethod = @this => true;
```

But how can I have different behaviours for both calls? When I write another line following the one above with "false" being returned, this "overwrites" the first one, so I'll always get false as a result.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit ugly, but possible:

```
var toggle = false;
MSomeInstance.SomeMethod.AllInstances.SomeMethod =
    @this => { toggle = !toggle; return toggle; };
```

The first call will return true, the second false.

Comment: This generally gets the job done. You can combine an index and an IEnumerable to make subsequent calls return successive entries in order.

Comment: Thanks, didn't think of such a solution, glad it works (it's only a special case anyway) :-)